# WARNING in Conflict: Multiple assets emit different content to the same filename vendor_styles.js.map

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-dev-server, mini-css-extract-plugin

I'm gettin these two warnings in my webpack output:

> WARNING in Conflict: Multiple assets emit different content to the
>   same filename custom_styles.js.map
>
> WARNING in Conflict: Multiple assets emit different content to the
>   same filename vendor_styles.js.map
>
> Child mini-css-extract-plugin
>   node_modules/css-loader/index.js!node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js!src/styles/main.scss:
>       Entrypoint mini-css-extract-plugin = *
>       [./node_modules/css-loader/index.js!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js!./src/styles/main.scss]
>   ./node_modules/css-loader!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js!./src/styles/main.scss
>   9.22 KiB {mini-css-extract-plugin} [built]
>           + 1 hidden module Child mini-css-extract-plugin node_modules/css-loader/index.js!node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js!src/styles/vendor.scss:
>       Entrypoint mini-css-extract-plugin = *
>       [./node_modules/css-loader/index.js!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js!./src/styles/vendor.scss]
>   ./node_modules/css-loader!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js!./src/styles/vendor.scss
>   1010 bytes {mini-css-extract-plugin} [built]
>           + 14 hidden modules

```
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');

const path = require('path');

const ROOT_PATH = path.resolve(__dirname);

// Compile all css into one css file
const ExtractPlugin = new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
  filename: '[name].bundle.css'
});

const baseConfig = {
  entry: {
    custom_styles: './src/styles/main.scss',
    vendor_styles: './src/styles/vendor.scss'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        loader: 'style-loader!css-loader'
      },
      {
        // Compile scss into css files
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, 'css-loader', 'sass-loader']
      }
    ]
  },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(ROOT_PATH, 'dist'),
    publicPath: '/',
    filename: '[name].bundle.js',
    chunkFilename: '[id].bundle.js'
  },
  plugins: [ExtractPlugin]
};

module.exports = (env, args) => baseConfig
```

Comment: pls read this thread https://github.com/webpack-contrib/mini-css-extract-plugin/issues/250#issuecomment-561067440

Answer (score 0):

that issues accrued in png/svg images you set to image name to unique

like (.edit/share_icon.png) and .update/share_icon.png

change to (.edit/share_icon_edit.png) and .update/share_icon_update.png